# How to do feature cross of brands and months

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, data-science, feature-engineering

Suppose I have three pandas dfs:

```
Brands           Months         Sales
       
hersheys         2020-08        $100
hersheys         2020-09        $200
snickers         2020-01        $20
reeses           2019-02        $200
...              ...
```

where months is the month in which we are looking at sales for a particular brand.
My question is, how can we feature cross brands and months to make a new feature 'BrandsxMonths'? From what I've seen online, only a Tensorflow using bucketing/binning is the only option, but is there any easier way to do it (such as using pandas, since we are dealing with dataframes)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you can do this:

```
df['BrandsxMonths'] = df['Brands'].astype(str) + df['Months'].astype(str)
```